# Country Colouring F#

Tags: f#, set, fold

I keep getting

```
'Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression'
```

when trying to compute a function.

Here is my code:

```
let colourTheCountries (chart: Chart)  = 
    Set.fold(extColouring chart) Set.empty Set.empty
```

How do I terminate the expression?

I want the value of the Set.fold to be the result.

Comment: Please look in the [F# tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) at previous answers. `'Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression' ` is a very common problem and should be easy to figure out by yourself. Also try using a search engine such as Google. I know you are in a class and this is hard for you as you are a beginner, but you need to acquire the skills to solve problems on your own. Show us that you at least looked for an answer and what you think is correct and we will then gladly help you.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you I did look around at the common mistakes but my code didn't seem to match any of them. Figured it out, it was a previous function being indented improperly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

After looking around on the internet I couldn't figure out why I was getting this error. I notice a function that was previously working below this one was also getting an error.

Turns out the functions above was indented by an extra space.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio then there is an extension [Visual F# Power Tools](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/) with a feature called [Depth colorizer](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/depthcolorizer.html) that will add vertical lines for code alignment. `You can install this extension in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 by searching for "FSharp Power Tools" in "Tools --> Extensions and Updates --> Online".`